# Rails project that is actively updated as a base

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm currently researching how I can create a standard rails project with some custom functionality as the basis for my next projects.

I know there are some tools for templating (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/rails_application_templates.html) a project but I don't know if they will suffice as I want to keep updating the template project with new stuff.

What are the ways to achieve this? Will git be the solution (rebase the new functionality) or is there anything else that is easier to manage?

Comment: +1 for templating idea -- didn't actually know about that!

Comment: Will a Rails engine fit the purpose?

Comment: That's actually a good recommendation andHapp, I will research this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you give more information on what you're trying to achieve?  You're a bit vague to be honest.

I don't see why templating wouldn't work

You could combine it with a generator, installed through a simple gem you've created that's defined in a Gemfile somewhere

```
remove_file 'Gemfile'
copy_file '/path/to/Gemfile', 'Gemfile'
run "bundle install"

generate("your_generator:install")
```

Comment: I'm trying to achieve a standard project with some gems configured, so it is reusable in new projects. But at the same time I want it to be updateable. For example: got a template, I start a new project with that template. Now I update my template, the next step is how can I update my project thats inherited from that template.

Comment: In which case andHapp is right an engine is probably the best way to go.